# reflect.Pointer() returned value is not the value address

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reflection

```
type BookInfo struct {
    Meta         *TableMeta
    ...
}

func (si *schemaInfo) getTabInfo(obj interface{}) (*tabInfo, error) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    if typ.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return nil, errors.New("nborm.schemaInfo.getDBInfo() error: required a pointer")
    }
    meta := *(**TableMeta)(unsafe.Pointer(val.Pointer()))
    ...
 }
```

`getTabInfo()` works well, but I want to know why `val.Pointer()` return a value of `**TableMeta`? Why not a `*TableMeta`?The document of `reflect` says,

> Pointer returns v's value as a uintptr. It returns uintptr instead of
>   unsafe.Pointer so that code using reflect cannot obtain
>   unsafe.Pointers without importing the unsafe package explicitly. It
>   panics if v's Kind is not Chan, Func, Map, Ptr, Slice, or
>   UnsafePointer.

In my mind:

```
info := &BookInfo{}
val := reflect.ValueOf(info)
ptr := val.Pointer()
meta := (*TableMeta)(unsafe.Pointer(val.Pointer()))
```

should work, but infact when I called `val.Pointer()`, the returned value is the pointer of `*TableMeta`(`**TableMeta`).

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You **asked** for a pointer, you got one. If you want the value call `Interface()` on the reflect.Value.

Comment: To clarify: The Pointer method returns you a "pointer to what you have". If you have a *TableMeta you get a **TableMeta. If you want the value back: Interface() and type assert.

Comment: In your last example, `info` is of type `*BookInfo`, so why are you attempting to get `*TableMeta` out of its `reflect.Value` wrapper? Obtain `*BookInfo` from it, then you can refer to its `Meta` field which will be of type `*TableMeta`. Same goes for the `getTabInfo()` function.

Comment: @icza the address of first field of struct and the address of struct is same.I tried it，it works

Comment: @wangjun Posted an answer to explain it.

Comment: @Volker I am learning English while learning programming. I am not good at it. Thanks for your comment，I think i understand it. But if Pointer() return the address of value, I think the document of reflect is not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you have is a pointer to a `BookInfo` struct, it is of type `*BookInfo`. And the type of `BookInfo.Meta` field is also a pointer, it is of type `*TableMeta`, thus a `*BookInfo` can then be looked at as `**TableMeta`, hence the "double" pointer.

It's true that the struct pointer points to its first field, but don't build on it. It's fragile. If you add a field before it, it'll break badly (which will only happen at runtime, no compile time messages due to package `unsafe`).

So if the value is of type `*BookInfo`, simply obtain that out of the `reflect.Value` wrapper, then you can refer to its field like `value.Meta`, which will be of type `*TableMeta`. Avoid using package `unsafe`, especially if it's not needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a figure, found the first field value is the address of TableMeta in heap. Thanks a lot

Comment: I want writ my own ORM package. I don’t want use reflect every query.so I make a cache to store model fields information when model first query. But when using field alone without model, I cannot get the database name nor table name, except store them to every field. So I want to use field offset to get the model meta data, the first field of each model must be a ‘*TableMeta’,so I only need store offset of field, when I want get the meta data, sub the offset of field from the address of field, then I get the model address, at the same time, get the meta data

Comment: @wangjun There are other ways that don't involve relying on this. E.g. you can use [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) to get a field by its string name.

Comment: If I only pass a field to some function, I can’t get the field name, because it is only a Field type, though it must be in a model. I defined some methods and interfaces to implement it in first version which not use reflect. But in that version the model definition is a little complex. So I want change it. But reflect is too slow, so I want to use it as less as needed. So I introduced unsafe. Forgive my poor English, I tried my best to explain clearly